# What is the best place to store my private keys?

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys, private-key

I recently started to change my SSH remote connections from password-authentication to SSH-key authentication. What's the best place to store my private keys? In the Cloud? External HD?

Thank you.

Comment: One option is to store it in your password manager if it allows you to save some files (LastPass does for example) - other ideas: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/where-do-you-store-your-personal-private-gpg-key

Comment: The important thing is that your keys should be stored where only *you* can get them.  This means that cloud storage isn't appropriate unless it's strongly encrypted.

Comment: Is your concern losing the key files and subsequently losing access to the remote machines? Note, you'll still be able to log in to the machine locally if you have physical access to the box.

Comment: My concern is for the private keys to be deleted/destroy due to bad SSD, etc. I just want to know some good practices

Comment: I think the [QR-code printing option](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/51776) is pretty nice.